# Method for posting data to web server from my app

Tags: ios, xcode, json

I have a fully developed website that I'd like to make an app for. I have a decent amount of experience with xcode from a game developing job I had a while ago, but I've never done anything with remote data before. I was hoping the community could point me in the direction of tutorials, code libraries or other resources that they have found helpful for posting information from apps to web servers.

I designed my site with an app in the back of my mind so all my database functions have their own php files that fill my site with json encoded data or insert/update database information so my app wouldn't have to connect directly to the database. I'm a quick study so once I get a pipeline set up between my app and the sever I should be good to go.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can find sample code that should get you start quickly [here][1] and [here][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456966/how-to-send-json-data-in-the-http-request-using-nsurlrequest
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518279/json-iphone-how-to-send-a-json-request-and-pull-the-data-from-a-server

Comment: Very helpful. Already working!

Answer (score 0):

Set up an [`NSURLRequest`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to your website and use an [`NSURLConnection`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to get the results and parse it with [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit)